# cannot connect to MySQL-server running on Docker with JDBC - Communication Link Failure

Tags: java, mysql, docker, jdbc

I have a Mysql-server docker instance with PORTS `3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp`.
I am trying to connect to it through JDBC but I keep receiving the error `Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`.
I have created a user `test` and a database also named `test`.

The code I am using is the following:

```java
package com.example.testconnection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String username = "test";
        String password = "password";

        System.out.println("Connecting database...");

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
            System.out.println("Database connected!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
        }

    }
}
```

built with Gradle, with the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.0'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.25'
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So, how are you running your mySql container? Have you checked `docker ps`?

Comment: yes I did, the ports of my `docker ps` are the ones I wrote above.. maybe I'm doing something wrong but the service is running at port 3306 on my host machine, maybe on the container is different

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace. I believe one of the 'caused by's delivers more information. Also provide a dump of 'docker ps' for your mysql container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by inspecting the mysql docker container with `docker inspect nameofmycontainer | grep IPAddress` and getting an IP e.g. `172.17.0.2`. Changing this IP address into the Java code, substituting `localhost`, will solve the issue!

Another important thing is making sure that the user has grants to connect outside of `localhost`. This can be achieved by doing
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`